# Does casting types depend on big/little endian?

Tags: c, casting, endianness

Consider this little piece of code:

```
int a=0x10000001;
char b;

b=(char)a;
printf("%#x \n",b);
```

On my PC it prints 0x01 and I am not suprised. 
How would it work on BIG ENDIAN machine? I expect that it would print `0x10000001`. Am I right?

I browsed books and web but I didn't find clear information how the casting operation really deals with the memory.

Comment: Please don't add adornments like "(C)" to the title - the tags you use mean that this is redundant. :-)

Comment: Btw, this example code does not have a well-defined result if `char` has 8 bits, for example.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes If `char` has 8 bits, what is not well defined about OP's example?

Comment: @chux 268435457 is not representable by `char`. (Ooops, I forgot to say "... and `char` is a signed type)

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes Of course 268435457 is not representable by an 8-bit `char`.  What are you suggesting then about the cast (char) does not provide well defined results?  UB, something else?

Comment: It produces an implementation defined value. It is perfectly valid for an implementation to print 0x10 for this code. Or, since there are no constraints this implementation-defined value has to fulfill, an implementation could simply make all such conversions always produce 0, which is probably the most efficient implementation possible (not the most useful, though :P)

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes  Interesting.  Have you come across a system that does not perform the a%256?  (or a&255)

Answer (score 18):

No, casting like the one in question does preserve value if possible and does not depend on memory representation.

If you want to reinterpret the memory representation you need to cast pointers. Then it will depend on endianness:

```
b=*((char*)&a);
```

Answer (score 8):

*Numbers* are not big- or little-endian. *Sequences of bytes* are big- or little-endian. Numbers are just numbers.

C's *numeric types* deal, unsurprisingly, with *numbers*, not with *sequences of bytes*.

Answer (score 2):

No. Endianness doesn't matter in this example. Converting to char (assuming a char is narrower than an int) will keep the lower-order bits, and lower-order bits are lower-order bits, no matter how they are stored in memory.

Answer (score 0):

C++ standard states the following:

> 5.2.3.1 A simple-type-specifier (7.1.5) followed by a parenthesized expression-list constructs a value of the specified type given the
>   expression list.

So yes, it constructs new instance demoting the wider type to shorter one regardless the binary representation. So if you're interested in exact part of the int to be passed to char, let use bitwise shift operator - it is platform-independent and produces predictable results.